# searchbar is not working in prototypecell

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8, uilocalnotification, localnotification

iam trying the programme on searchbar,when i implement the search bar in table view it is working,but the problem is when i am implementing seachbar for same code for prototypecell it is not working,the seachbar  controller is not working please solve my problem.i written all the code perfectly

actually iam doing this in the storyboard i am using the xcode 5.1

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 contactcell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[contactcell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

```
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you already done the programme,so need to answer